# Which code to unit-test?

Tags: unit-testing

It is widely accepted, that UT's are necessary for any large project with automated testing. However, it is rarely the case, that 100% of the production code is covered by UT's.

There are of course, marginal cases, where UT's are useless waste of resources, e.g. simple setters/getters. On the other hand, there are cases with complex code, tens of LOC (might also be a candidate for refactoring, but still it would not break the single large block of source code into primitive one-liners, as it has some more complex logic than usual), e.g. some complex numeric algorithm, that is definitely worth unit-testing. And there are cases of all kinds of complexity in between those two marginal cases.

Are there any practical source code metrics, that would unambiguously spot good candidates (functions, procedures or methods) for unit-testing?

Comment: Only unit test the functions that you want to work correctly.  Any functions that can be buggy and do the wrong thing don't need to be tested.

Comment: If you write the unit test first, as part of the process of writing your code, then you never have to worry.  It seems a little counter-intuitive but this may actually save you time.  It will also help you design your code, since you start by thinking your way through exactly what your code needs to do to pass your unit test

Answer (score 4):

**With only the Unit Tests, Could This Code Be Written?**

*The answer is probably no.*

Your first unambiguous metric that indicates a need for Unit Tests.

In this case a Unit Test should prove a quality about the system, we do not care how the quality is achieved, merely that it is present.

eg:

```
[TestCase("A")]
[TestCase("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")]
void Padding_a_smaller_string_to_40_characters_always_makes_a_40_character_string(string a_small_string);
```

Should that pass, the system has this property, when it doesn't the system does not have this property.

**Would the Newly Written Code work like the Old Deleted Code?**

*Again probably not.*

Your second unambiguous metric that indicates a need for Unit Tests.

In this case we still do not care about specific implementation, but we do care that swapping this program for the old one does not confuse anyone. The same inputs are still accepted, the same behaviour happens, the same outputs occur, all in the same order.

These probably are no longer unit tests, they are best described as module tests, integration tests, business tests, acceptance tests, or end to end tests. But they are no less important. You still want your text editor to act like a text editor should it be rewritten.

**Can I Understand the Purpose of this Module from a listing of Unit Test Titles?**

*The answer is probably no*

Your third unambiguous metric that indicates a need for Unit Tests.

The Unit Test is not actually a test. It serves two purposes:

- Something has changed (A Check)
- What that something was. (Design Documentation)

The first part is achieved by executing the test. When it passes 'nothing' has supposedly changed. Otherwise it has.

The second part is a conversation with whoever is responding to the failure. They might not be a developer. They might be new to that code. So the test has to document what the point of the check was (what is designed to happen). Then whoever responds can say, 'yes that was expected', or 'no. what went wrong?'.

**I'm not deleting my code, why all this fuss about writing it from the tests!?**

Because that is what happens every day on any actively maintained/developed piece of software.

Pieces of the software are being amended and rewritten from scratch with nothing but those unit tests as a guide.

**Pragmatic Testing**

If you do have an untested code base, or the tests are next to useless obviously you will need to prioritise.

Even on very well tested code bases things are omitted, knowledge is lost, things grow stale.

Unless you have the luxury of doing anything, the piece of code to improve the tests on is dictated by the next feature/bug fix.

Approach:

1. Before implementing a feature, before designing a feature, review the tests, and the code.

   - Any untested code is a RISK.
   - Poorly written tests are a RISK.
2. Reduce the RISK by learning what was actually designed, and why. This will likely involve reading a lot of code, and discussing it with many people some of them might even be users. Document each property as a test. Expanding on, or updating existing tests.

   - When do you stop documenting? When you are comfortable that you thoroughly understand the current and acceptable behaviour of the module (The RISK is low enough that you can handle it).
3. Design the new/amended feature and document it in tests.

   - This will take some effort, design is hard.
   - New and amended tests will fail

     - if they are passing because it was an undocumented feature, turn the feature off/disable it. If something else breaks you did not understand the current implementation, go back to step 2.
     - if the tests still are not failing, you didn't understand the current implementation, go back to step 2.
4. Implement the new/amended feature, or re-enable it.

   - The feature is implemented when the tests pass.
5. Rework the feature until it is clean

If you do happen to live in luxury and can choose which piece of code to tackle next, how did you get there?

But more seriously do not just write tests for the sake of it, code that is not being changed does not need to be documented.

Change can come from backlogs, tech debt, operational features, stream lining, platform uplifts, and your own pet peeve (you work in this code base, make it comfortable). These are all sources to guide you on picking the next piece of code to tackle.

Should you run out of change, you now officially have a dead system.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my practical function for determining whether you should unit test something.

```
public bool ShouldITest(string functionName)
{
    return true;
}
```

There is a massive benefit in having 100% test coverage. The benefit of one less human decision required. One less thing that *might* be wrong. One less thing that can't be automated, or automatically discounted.

We have to apply our own profession to itself. Automate software development as much as you can, standardise, create a manual process, automate that process.

Comment: Unless it is some _formal_ verification required by industry adopted standards, I am sceptical about the real value of such generalized statements like "Do 100% coverage with UT's. Fullstop." I mean, the same piece of code could have been tested by functional/integration/system tests, and one should not exclude those higher level types of testing anyway, right? So there is also and always trade-off in each particular type of testing in overall testing activities.

Comment: You can always argue in favour of shortcuts with anything. The point is to reduce the cost to zero. Not to stop doing things because they have cost.

Comment: There's no such thing as 100% test coverage, in theory or in practice.

Comment: surely you can imagine a trival single boolean function being 100% tested?

Comment: Those aren't the kind of functions I'm thinking about.

Comment: so you admit the "theory" part of your statement is incorrect!!!! 10 points to griffindor